# How to change all keys to lowercase when parsing JSON to a JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema, json-deserialization

I have a string of JSON and the keys have uppercase and lowercase characters:

```
{"employees":[
    {"FIrstName":"John", "LASTname":"Doe"},
    {"FIRSTNAME":"Anna", "LaSTNaME":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

I want convert it to a `JToken` object and have all the keys in the `JToken` be lowercase. So internally in the `JToken` it should be as follows:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstname":"John", "lastname":"Doe"},
    {"firstname":"Anna", "lastname":"Smith"},
    {"firstname":"Peter", "lastname":"Jones"} 
]}
```

Previously I was using `JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonString);` to convert, but I can't find out how to make the keys lowercase. **Any ideas?**

The reason why I need to do this is so that my `JsonSchema` validation will be case insensitive.

Comment: JProperty has only getter for Name so I think you will have problems changing it.

Comment: True. I was thinking there was some way to customize the parsing mechanism. Similar to the js parse function that has the reviver parameter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to edit the parsing. I'm just not sure how to customize in json.net.

Comment: if you want to create custom Json converter, check this out. I don't know if it will help in your current case:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Comment: Use this, perhaps, after loading the JSON?  [Json.net rename properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679804/json-net-rename-properties).

Comment: @Jim Why did you remove your answer? Although it didn't help in my situation, it could help other users.

Comment: @Rafi I was just not sure if it was suited to leave it, since you can't use `.IsValid(sheme)` on a deserialized object :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way to solve this with minimal code is to subclass the `JsonTextReader` and override the `Value` property to return a lowercase string whenever the current `TokenType` is `PropertyName`:

```
public class LowerCasePropertyNameJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public LowerCasePropertyNameJsonReader(TextReader textReader)
        : base(textReader)
    {
    }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                return ((string)base.Value).ToLower();

            return base.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the underlying `JsonTextReader` keeps the `TokenType` updated as its internal state changes, and the serializer (actually the `JsonSerializerInternalReader` class) relies on that when it goes to retrieve the property name from the reader via the `Value` property.

You can create a short helper method to make it easy to deserialize using the custom reader:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static JToken DeserializeWithLowerCasePropertyNames(string json)
    {
        using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(json))
        using (JsonReader jsonReader = new LowerCasePropertyNameJsonReader(textReader))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            return ser.Deserialize<JToken>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code, just replace this:

```
JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
```

with this:

```
JToken json = JsonHelper.DeserializeWithLowerCasePropertyNames(jsonString);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A0S3I1

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. It changes to lowercase on parsing which is the most effecient.

Comment: I'd recommend using `ToLowerInvariant()` rather than `ToLower()` to avoid inconsistencies across locales e.g. with the [turkish I](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html).