# Change key name of data loaded through JsonExtensionData

Tags: json.net

I have a JSON resulting from a mix of system data and user entries, like this :

```
{
    "Properties": [{
        "Type": "A",
        "Name": "aaa",
        "lorem ipsum": 7.1
    }, {
        "Type": "B",
        "Name": "bbb",
        "sit amet": "XYZ"
    }, {
        "Type": "C",
        "Name": "ccc",
        "abcd": false
    }]
}
```

I need to load it, process it, and save it to MongoDB. I deserialize it to this class :

```
public class EntityProperty {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> OtherProperties { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that MongoDB does not allow dots in key names, but the users can do whatever they want.

So I need a way to save this additional JSON data but I also need to change the key name as it's being processed.

I tried to add `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomValuesConverter))]` to the `OtherProperties` attribute but it seems to ignore it.

**Update/Clarification**: since the serialization is done by Mongo (I send the objects to the library), I need the extension data names to be fixed during **deserialization**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Since the fixing of names must be done during *deserialization*, you could generalize the `LowerCasePropertyNameJsonReader` from [How to change all keys to lowercase when parsing JSON to a JToken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877985) by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) to perform the necessary transformation.

First, define the following:

```
public class PropertyNameMappingJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    readonly Func<string, string> nameMapper;

    public PropertyNameMappingJsonReader(TextReader textReader, Func<string, string> nameMapper)
        : base(textReader)
    {
        if (nameMapper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.nameMapper = nameMapper;
    }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                return nameMapper((string)base.Value);
            return base.Value;
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json, Func<string, string> nameMapper, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(json))
        using (var jsonReader = new PropertyNameMappingJsonReader(textReader, nameMapper))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
 var root = JsonExtensions.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, (s) => s.Replace(".", ""));
```

Or, if you are deserializing from a `Stream` via a `StreamReader` you can construct your `PropertyNameMappingJsonReader` directly from it.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iXEAfy).

Alternatively, you could also fix the extension data in an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback, but I think this solution is neater because it avoids adding logic to the objects themselves.

**Original Answer**

Assuming you are using [Json.NET 10.0.1 or later](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1), you can create your own custom [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm), override [`NamingStrategy.GetExtensionDataName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_GetExtensionDataName.htm), and implement the necessary fix.

First, define `MongoExtensionDataSettingsNamingStrategy` as follows:

```
public class MongoExtensionDataSettingsNamingStrategy : DefaultNamingStrategy
{
    public MongoExtensionDataSettingsNamingStrategy()
        : base()
    {
        this.ProcessExtensionDataNames = true;
    }

    protected string FixName(string name)
    {
        return name.Replace(".", "");
    }

    public override string GetExtensionDataName(string name)
    {
        if (!ProcessExtensionDataNames)
        {
            return name;
        }
        return name.Replace(".", "");
    }
}
```

Then serialize your root object as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new MongoExtensionDataSettingsNamingStrategy() },
};
var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);
```

Notes:

- Here I am inheriting from `DefaultNamingStrategy` but you could inherit from [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) if you prefer.
- The naming strategy is only invoked to remap extension data names (and dictionary keys) during serialization, not deserialization.
- You may want to [cache the contract resolver for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).
- There is no built-in attribute to specify a converter for dictionary *keys*, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845364/3744182).  And in any event Json.NET would not use the `JsonConverter` applied to `OtherProperties` since the presence of the `JsonExtensionData` attribute supersedes the converter property.

Alternatively, if it would be more convenient to specify the naming strategy using [Json.NET serialization attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm), you will need a slightly different naming strategy.  First create:

```
public class MongoExtensionDataAttributeNamingStrategy : MongoExtensionDataSettingsNamingStrategy
{
    public MongoExtensionDataAttributeNamingStrategy()
        : base()
    {
        this.ProcessDictionaryKeys = true;
    }

    public override string GetDictionaryKey(string key)
    {
        if (!ProcessDictionaryKeys)
        {
            return key;
        }
        return FixName(key);
    }        
}
```

And modify `EntityProperty` as follows:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(MongoExtensionDataAttributeNamingStrategy))]
public class EntityProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> OtherProperties { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for the inconsistency is that, as of Json.NET 10.0.3, `DefaultContractResolver` uses `GetDictionaryKey()` when remapping extension data names using a naming strategy that is set via attributes [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L335), but uses `GetExtensionDataName()` when the naming strategy is set via settings [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1633).  I have no explanation for the inconsistency; it feels like a bug.

Comment: It's a very good answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem... since the serialization is done by Mongo (I send the objects to the library), and your solution works on **de**serialization... For now I have solved it with poorly written `JsonConverter`s but I would love to learn of a better solution, your "naming strategy" feels much nicer.

Comment: @thomasb - answer updated using new information.

Comment: Oh my. I can't upvote twice ! :D It works perfectly, thanks ! But now my question is a duplicate... I'll mark it as such.